# cant get the perl regex to work

Tags: regex, perl

My perl is getting rusty. It only prints "matched=" but $1 is blank!?!

**EDIT 1: WHo the h#$! downvoted this? There are no wrong questions. If you dont like it, move on to next one!**

```
$crazy="abcd\r\nallo\nXYZ\n\n\nQQQ";
if ($crazy =~ m/([.\n\r]+)/gsi) {
    print "matched=", $1, "\n";
} else {
    print "not matched!\n";
}
```

**EDIT 2: This is the code fragment with updated regex, works great!**

```
$crazy="abcd\r\nallo\nXYZ\n\n\nQQQ";
if ($crazy =~ m/([\s\S]+)/gsi) {
    print "matched=", $1, "\n";
} else {
    print "not matched!\n";
}
```

**EDIT 3: Haha, i see perl police strikes yet again!!!**

Comment: What exactly do you want to match?

Comment: `ord($1)` returns 13, so it's matching the first `\r`.

Comment: everything, the whole string, that's what i expect to be printed

Comment: @Mike but i have the + after the brackets, it should greedly match entire string, no?

Comment: @Saideira No, the + means to match whatever is in the character class one or more times.  Your regex is looking for sequences of one or more `.`, `\n` or `\r`.  I'm not clear on what you are expecting the result to be. Why do you expect the whole string to be returned?

Comment: @Mike, i thought dot, CR, LF will match *any* char in a text file. I expect the entire string to be printed, but apparently dot inside the [] has a different meaning. BTW I got it to work the way i want by using [\s\S]+

Comment: @Saideira I'm still confused :-)  It's unusual to want to match a whole string with a regex...

Comment: @Saideira let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1235/discussion-between-mike-and-saideira)

Comment: Finally, the "." metacharacter matches any character except "\n" (unless you use /s). http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: Edit 2: `[\s\S]` will also match any character, like period `.`.. If it works "great", that's only coincidence.

Comment: @TLP how's it a coincidence? [\s\S] matches *any* char, including CR, LF, etc, which is what my question was about

Comment: Your question was something about a regex not working, as near as I can tell. If you wanted to match any char, period is how you do that.

Comment: You are getting downvoted because your question is unclear. If you think \s\S solves your question, then the downvotes are in order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is your exact problem, but inside square brackets, `'.'` is just looking for a period. I didn't see a period in the input, so I wondered which you meant.

Aside from the period, the rest of the character class is looking for consecutive whitespace. And as you didn't use the **m**ultiline switch, you've got newlines being counted as whitespace (and any character), but no indication to scan beyond the first record separator. But because of the way that you print it out, it also gives some indication that you meant more than the literal period, as mentioned above.

Comment: my goal is to match every single char (obviously, this is a simplified example). Dot matches every char, except new lines symbol, so i have them together inside brackets. It doesnt matter if i put "m" in front or at the end of reg ex, $1 still is blank

Comment: @Saideira, See my first remark. "Dot matches every char, except new lines symbol" -- except when *within a character class* (square brackets)

Comment: Yes, in a character class, a dot is just a dot. Your /s has no affect there.

Answer (score 3):

Axeman is correct; your problem is that `.` in a character class doesn't do what you expect.

By default, `.` outside a character class (and not backslashed) matches any character but a newline.  If you want to include newlines, you specify the /s flag (which you seem to already have) on your regex or put the `.` in a `(?s:...)` group:

```
my $crazy="abcd\r\nallo\nXYZ\n\n\nQQQ";
if ($crazy =~ m/((?s:.+))/) {
    print "matched=", $1, "\n";
} else {
    print "not matched!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$1` contains white space, that's why you don't see it in a print like that, just add something after it/quote it.

Example:

```
perl -E "qq'abcd\r\nallo\nXYZ\n\n\nQQQ'=~/([.\n\r]+)/gsi;say 'got(',length($1),qq') >$1<';"
got(2) >
<
```

**Updated** for your comments:

To match everything you can simply use `/(.+)/s`

Comment: @Saideira, updated. For my example you probably need Perl 5.12 or newer, because I use `-E` and `say`, you can just replace those with `-e` and `print`.

Comment: @Saideria What version of Perl are you using?  The code Qtax sent you requires Perl 5.10 or later (the `-E` flag is new as of 5.10 and turns on optional features like the `say` function).

Answer (score 2):

`.` in a character class is a literal period, not match anything.  What you really want is `/(.+)/s`.  The `/g` flag says to match multiple times, but you are using the regex in scalar context, so it will only match the first item.  The `/i` flag makes the regex case insensitive, but there are no characters with case in your regex.  The `\s` flag makes `.` match newlines, and it always matches `"\r"`, so instead of `[.\n\r]`, you can just use `.`.

However, `/(.+)/s` will match any string with one or more characters, so you would be better off with

```
my $crazy="abcd\r\nallo\nXYZ\n\n\nQQQ";

if (length $crazy) {
    print "matched=$crazy\n";
} else {
    print "not matched!\n";
}
```

It is possible you meant to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $crazy = "abcd\r\nallo\nXYZ\n\n\nQQQ";

while ($crazy =~ /(.+)[\r\n]+/g) {
    print "matched=$1\n";
}
```

But that would probably be better phrased:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $crazy = "abcd\r\nallo\nXYZ\n\n\nQQQ";

for my $part (split /[\r\n]+/, $crazy) {
    print "matched=$part\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`[.]` (dot inside a character class) does not mean "match any character", it just means match the literal `.` character. So in an input string without any dots,

```
m/([.\n\r]+)/gsi
```

will just match strings of `\n` and `\r` characters.
With the `/s` modifier, you are already asking the regex engine to include newlines with `.` (match any character), so you could just write

```
m/(.+)/gsi
```

Comment: `/i` is useless in that regex (there are no upper or lower case characters for it to affect).